# Is it possible in Go to call a function with named arguments?

Tags: function, go, arguments, named

I want to call a function in Go, and attach to the argument values the argument names

```golang
func sum(a int, b int) int {
  return a + b
}

func main() {
  result := sum(a=4, b=5) // result == 9
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing like named arguments in `go`

Comment: you refer to `a` and `b` as local arguments, I mentioned them as the arguments in the function signature.
But I understand, there is no such thing named arguments in go...Thanks!

Comment: Nothing illogical about the ask. Such option exists in python exists, and it makes the code self documenting in many situations

Comment: Specifying the parameter when calling a function makes it much more clear what information is being passed and there's no harm in letting the compiler allow it if the parameters are still ordered properly. Initializing variables in the parameters may not be OK, but a=4; b=5; result := sum(a=a, b=b) is what I would like to see possible.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment Go does not have a way to use named argument in functions.
If you really need to use named arguments you can try this library [go-named-params](https://github.com/elliotchance/go-named-params)

Comment: I saw this repo, I preferred to avoid unnecessary packages.
Thanks